# Revolution slider stop and start on click

Tags: jquery, slider

I am using jQuery revolution slider to my site. I want to ***stop*** and ***start*** slider on ***click***. How can I do it.

```
$('.rev-slider-banner-full').revolution({
    delay: 7000,
    startwidth: 960,
    startheight: 600,
    onHoverStop: "off",
    thumbWidth: 100,
    thumbHeight: 50,
    thumbAmount: 3,
    hideThumbs: 0,
    navigationType: "none",
    navigationArrows: "solo",
    navigationStyle: "bullets",
    navigationHAlign: "center",
    navigationVAlign: "bottom",
    navigationHOffset: 30,
    navigationVOffset: 30,
    soloArrowLeftHalign: "left",
    soloArrowLeftValign: "center",
    soloArrowLeftHOffset: 20,
    soloArrowLeftVOffset: 0,
    soloArrowRightHalign: "right",
    soloArrowRightValign: "center",
    soloArrowRightHOffset: 20,
    soloArrowRightVOffset: 0,
    touchenabled: "on",
    stopAtSlide: -1,
    stopAfterLoops: -1,
    hideCaptionAtLimit: 0,
    hideAllCaptionAtLilmit: 0,
    hideSliderAtLimit: 0,
    fullWidth: "on",
    fullScreen: "off",
    fullScreenOffsetContainer: "#topheader-to-offset",
    shadow: 0
});
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[This (rather brief) API page](http://www.themepunch.com/codecanyon/revolution/liveguide/09.Sample-Api.html) explains the functions you can use with [Revolution Slider](http://themes.themepunch.com/?theme=revolution_jq), such as `revpause()` and `revresume()`.

So if you want to stop the slider when a button is clicked, you need to have the button (or a link tag) somewhere on your page.  Example...

```
<button id="stopButton">Stop</button>
<button id="resumeButton">Resume</button>
```

Then use the following jQuery...

```
// When stop button is clicked...
$('#stopButton').on('click', function(e){ 
    $('.rev-slider-banner-full').revpause();
});

// When resume button is clicked...
$('#resumeButton').on('click', function(e){ 
    $('.rev-slider-banner-full').revresume();
});
```

Replace `.rev-slider-banner-full` with the class or ID of your slider element if it differs.